# How to find all variations of addition given a list of numbers - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, addition

Say I have a list of numbers `[2,8,16]` and I wanted to find all of the unique sums I could have from this (in this case they would be: `2,8,16,10,18,24,26`)

Is there an easy way I can do this in Python3?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way via [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

```
from itertools import combinations

lst = [2, 8, 16]

result = sorted({sum(i) for j in range(1, len(lst)+1) for i in combinations(lst, j)})
# [2, 8, 10, 16, 18, 24, 26]
```

Comment: I should have stated:  the removal of duplicates is what is needed; so this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Lecture:
[chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)
and [chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)
and [combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

**Partial sums with output of the summands:**

```
import itertools
nums = [2,8,16]

sums = itertools.chain( itertools.combinations(nums, r=n) for n in range(1,len(nums)+1))

for it in  sums:
    for s in it:
        print ( f"sum({s}) = {s if isinstance(s,int) else sum(s)}")
```

Output:

```
sum((2,)) = 2
sum((8,)) = 8
sum((16,)) = 16
sum((2, 8)) = 10
sum((2, 16)) = 18
sum((8, 16)) = 24
sum((2, 8, 16)) = 26
```

**The *boring* one would be:**

```
sums = itertools.chain( itertools.combinations(nums, r=n) for n in range(1,len(nums)+1))
print( [sum(s) for it in sums for s in it])
```

Output:

```
[2, 8, 16, 10, 18, 24, 26]
```

**The one you could have found by researchin [itertools-recipes: powerset](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):**

```
from itertools import chain, combinations 
nums = [2,8,6,16]

def powerset(iterable):
    """powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)

     Credit to: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes"""
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

print( sorted([sum(s) for s in powerset(nums) if s])) #sorted + remove empty tuple
```

Output:

```
[2, 6, 8, 8, 10, 14, 16, 16, 18, 22, 24, 24, 26, 30, 32]
```

> **Sidenote:** these solutions will conserve duplicate sums. Put them in `list(set(result))` to remove duplicates, maybe using `sorted()` to order them. This was not part of the original question but added as comment to the accepted answer.